# Как получить текст заголовка вместо [<Element title at 0x7f7ecaa11ba8>]

Tags: html, python-3.x, utf-8, парсер, lxml

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь самоучиться по питону, затык с парсингом.

```
import lxml.html, urllib
page = urllib.urlopen('http://site.ru/').read() #сделали запрос на сайт и сохранили в переменную
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page)
advice = doc.xpath('//title') #нашли значение тега и сохранили в переменную
print (advice)
```

Все это выводит title в таком формате:

```
[<Element title at 0x7f7ecaa11ba8>]
```

Как мне получить нормальный русский текст вместо некого hex'а?

Comment: Логично, Вы пытаетесь распечатать не содержимое объекта, а его самого. А он не умеет себя красиво печатать. Попробуйте так
`print (advice.text_content())`

Comment: @KoVadim судя по выводу, advice это список. У списка нет, `text_content()` метода. Можно `[0]` попробовать. Связанный вопрос: [How can I retrieve the page title of a webpage using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/51233)

Comment: да, давно я этим не занимался. Исправляюсь - где то так `advice[0].text_content()`

Comment: @jfs advice[0].text_content() - искомое, спасибо KoVadim

Answer (score 1):

> Как мне получить нормальный русский текст вместо некого hex'а?

```
title_text = advice[0].text_content()
```

Даёт искомое, спасибо [@KoVadim комментарию выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581989/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-element-title-at-0x7f7ecaa11ba8#comment774549_581989).